# Flutter : Unable to navigate to next screen getting consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

when i am trying to navigate screen i am getting this error

Error is this
**consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted"**

Answer (score 0):

on line 81 write `if(mounted){ //your code }`

Comment: this is not working i have tried

Answer (score 0):

i suspect the issue is with the widget being already disposed, look at the line before this

> flutter (11689): Consider canceling

in your log, it says the widget was already unmounted and you're trying to access the context,
also consider using this instead of timer (which i also suspect is causing an issue)

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:3))
```

then navigating

Comment: this answer making code making same error looplessly

Comment: well then, you're probably calling this function after the widget was closed